# Why is my internet under 17.10 no longer working?

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, broadcom

Oddly on my Ubuntu system (I should warn ye that I'm using i3) the internet is no longer working. When I first started using i3 it was. In fact I think I had rebooted three times, after starting to use i3 exclusively, before I could no longer connect to the WiFi. I know how to start the internet under i3, I use `nmtui` to find a network (I'm using WiFi so it's especially important as I need to provide a password), activate the connection and the net should be there. After first activating the connection I want this should no longer be necessary, even after multiple reboots, as it should automatically connect to the WiFi.

On my other installed distros that are also using i3 (e.g. my Debian system is) the WiFi is working fine (same network too!). Under Ubuntu I've tried re-activating the WiFi connection, running `modprobe -a wl` (as I use a BCM4352 chip), which returns no error, and running `depmod -a && modprobe -a wl`. Still no resolution in sight. The only thing I can think of is regenerating resolv.conf, I've DuckDuckGo searched how to do this on Ubuntu 17.10 (an answer here exists for a pre-systemd Ubuntu release) but I haven't found anything. `/etc/resolv.conf` does exist.

https://pastebin.com/vw0AWiM0 is the output of iwconfig on this Ubuntu system. `iwlist wlo1 scan` output returns: https://pastebin.com/ga31DeTd.

Comment: check the ouput of `dmesg` after trying to connect to the wifi. Also `cat /var/log/syslog` might be a good place to look for errors.

Comment: I looked through both. Here's dmesg http://paste.debian.net/1014705, and here's syslog https://drive.google.com/open?id=10rOdjmJ9hj2UzoQ-Pd_g1Fz6CGXXs2tq. There's a few lines that seem suspicious like the `state change: unavailable -> disconnected` in syslog. Not sure what to do though.

Answer (score 1):

## Debug WLAN connection

If the WLAN is not working and the GUI frontent of the Network-Manger does not help. First check if the hardware is working properly by looking at `dmesg`

```
$ dmesg
...
[   13.899555] wlan0: Broadcom BCM43b1 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.271 (r587334)
...
[   14.845234] wl 0000:07:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
...
```

If there is a wlan device, the hardware drivers/module is working.

Install the wireless-tools and look at the interfaces:

Install tools wireless tools:

```
$ sudo apt-get install wireless-tools
```

Check the WLAN interfaces:

```
$ sudo iwconfig
wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"NetworkSSID"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.56 GHz  Access Point: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX   
          Bit Rate=400 Mb/s   Tx-Power=200 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=69/70  Signal level=-41 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Scan on the current interface:

```
$ sudo iwlist wlo1 scan
wlo1      Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
                    Channel:112
                    Frequency:5.56 GHz
                    Quality=69/70  Signal level=-41 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"NetworkSSID"
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 16ms ago
                    ...
```

It looks like the encryption is not activated on the WLAN device. Try setting the key manually by setting:

```
$ iwconfig wlo1 key s:secretkey
```

Read the [iwconfig manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/iwconfig.8.html) for the proper syntax!

For the error messesage

```
Error for wireless request "Set Encode" (8B2A) :
    SET failed on device wlo1 ; Invalid argument.
```

check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/42460/can-you-explain-how-to-understand-what-the-iwconfig-command-displays-in-ubuntu) post on superuser. It might help.

For testing the wireless connection, I recommend using the manual configuration via `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto wlo1
iface wlo1 inet dhcp 
                wpa-ssid <ssid>
                wpa-psk  <password>
```

You can test it with:

```
$ ifup wlo1
$ ifdown wlo1
```

Comment: Well I ran diff on the output of running `iwconfig` on both Ubuntu and my Debian 9 install on the same PC. Other than things that change with time (hence may have differed between the times I had each distro booted) I noticed that Ubuntu 17.10 had the "Power Management" field set to "on" on the wlo1 connection while Debian 9, for which the WiFi was working, did not. So I tried to change it on the Ubuntu 17.10 system by running `iwconfig wlo1 power off`. This did not work, `iwconfig` kept reporting this field as being "on". Any ideas?

Comment: @BH2017  can you add the output to your question?

Comment: What output exactly? Just iwconfig from my Ubuntu system, or from both? Or do you also want me to include the iwlist output too? I assumed it was just the Ubuntu outputs so I added them to the question.

Comment: The output of the wireless-tools commands (`iwconfig`, `iwlist wlo1 scan|`). It is hard to guess without seeing the actual output.

Comment: Well they're in my question now.

Comment: I updated the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: I read the man page before you even updated it, but I've always found man pages at best 60% helpful. This one confuses me a little, what's the secret key? The network's password? If so I've tried that and I got the error `Error for wireless request "Set Encode" (8B2A) :
    SET failed on device wlo1 ; Invalid argument.`. wlo1 existed though. I'm kind of stuck here. Thanks for your attempts to help though, to be clear I am grateful. :)